# Can the adjective phrase ‘so powerful’ be a postmodifier?

Tags: modifiers

When I saw this sentence first, I thought *so powerful* to be an objective complement. [ ‘so powerful’ is the result of ‘make’] But now, it may be more reasonable to think ‘so powerful’ is modifying ‘a sleeping potion.’ Can the adjective phrase ‘so powerful’ be a postmodifier?

For your information Potter, asphodel and wormwood make a sleeping potion ***so powerful*** it is known as the Draught of the Living Death.

Comment: Yes - _so powerful_, or rather the complete clause, is postmodifying _a sleeping potion_ not _make_. Other similar constructions could be used, beginning _powerful enough to_, _capable of_, _able to_, ... ; as Robusto says in his answer, the elided words _that is_ would make the affiliation (noun phrase - postmodifier) clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call this simple *ellipsis*, the removal of words that are readily understood in their absence. Put the words back in and you have

> [A]sphodel and wormwood make a sleeping potion *that is* so powerful *that* it is known as the Draught of the Living Death.